# HTML5 video element with undesired play icon (ionic/android/videogular)

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-video, videogular

A big rectangle play icon is appearing in my videogular video player - when the video loads it sits on top of the icon (which still shows above). See image for example. On the left is the big playbutton, on the right is after the video loads, but the playbutton is still partially visible. I would like to eradicate that big icon. The same app on ios doesn't have this problem. I can't seem to discover what element is causing the overlay. I think it's getting drawn on the  or inner element: .

This is an ionic app on Android and I am using Videogular player.

[image: The big video icon that I can't seem to get rid of]

Comment: Facing same issue. Please help

Comment: You are using ionic v1?